# I want to transfer the content from one spread sheet to another spreadsheet(spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B) and also to enter records to B manually

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I want to transfer the contents from one spreadsheet to another spreadsheet(spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B) whenever if I do changes in spreadsheet A it has to be reflected in spreadsheet B. At the same time, I should also be able to add elements directly to spreadsheet B. I tried importrange function, it was transferring the contents from A to B but it is not allowing me to manually add things to spreadsheet B.

Answer (score 1):

**The best approach you could take for this is to use Apps Script.**

Some methods which can be of help to you:

- `openById` - which is used to retrieve each spreadsheet by their ids;
- `getSheetByName` - which is used to retrieve the sheets from the spreadsheets;
- `getRange` - which is used to retrieve the range in which the values can be found;
- `getValues` - which is used to retrieve the values from the specified range;
- `setValues` - which is used to place the values to the specified range;

Moreover, if you want to have the changes from one spreadsheet reflected on another, you can also make use of an `onEdit` trigger.

#### Reference

- [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String));
- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getSheetByName(String));
- [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getValues());
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object));
- [onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).